# Which temporal logic is the one described in Manna & Pnueli's "The Temporal Logic of Reactive and Concurrent Systems: Specification"?

Tags: temporal-logic

The Wikipedia article on temporal logic [lists many varieties of temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Temporal_logics), such as LTL (linear temporal logic), CTL (computation tree logic), CTL*, and others. Which of these is the logic described in Manna & Pnueli's textbook *The Temporal Logic of Reactive and Concurrent Systems: Specification*?

I've started to read Manna & Pnueli's textbook. I'd like to read other accounts of the same theory. But to do so I need to know the name of the theory, so I can look for other textbooks about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTL.

PS The very book you mention has a historical note section discussing various other temporal logics near page 271.

**Edit (leaving the above intact for the comments to make sense):** None of the named logics in the wikipedia article (at the time of writing this) is the same as/equivalent to Manna and Pnueli's. The name LTL has however a different and broader meaning in the community.

Comment: Judging by [the Wikipedia article on Linear temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic), the logic presented in Manna & Pnueli's textbook is not LTL, since LTL is propositional, whereas Manna & Pnueli's logic allows quantification over non-propositional variables. The historical note section in the textbook (titled *Bibliographic Notes*, and starting on p. 268) is of no help to me in answering my question.

Comment: Well, perhaps one should not judge by wikipedia then.  
In the community, LTL is colloquially understood as "what Manna & Pnueli did in their books". This is of course a bit sloppy. Some papers omit the past-time operators present on the books, others some quantifiers.  The propositional version called LTL in that wikipedia article is otherwise known as _Propositional Temporal Logic_ (p. 269 M&P'90) or _PLTL_ (e.g. in Emerson's chapter on _Temporal and Modal Logic_ in vol B of the [_Handbook of Computer Science_](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/533712)).

Comment: I'll edit my "answer" to clarify that the while the name is one used in the wikipedia article, it's got a different meaning.

Comment: OK. I'll accept your answer thanks to the citation in your penultimate comment of Emerson's chapter in volume B of *Handbook of Computer Science*. I checked in said chapter (which was reviewed by Amir Pnueli), and it indeed looks like the temporal logic in Manna & Pnueli's textbook is First Order Linear Temporal Logic.